# ASP.Net - Maximize and Close icon allignment issue with RadWindow

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I am using telerik radwindow to display a pdf.
Window is working fine and there is an alignment issue the maximize and close icon. Its expected to have in one row, buts rendered as in two columns. I am attaching the screen shots.

At the end of the window the close and restore icons were aligned not in a proper way. 
[image]

As I examine the html generated, I found that its a  element.

[image]

I tried, increase the width of main div, change the class added new class with different property values etc. But still I am not able to fix. Any thoughts or suggestion were highly welcome. Thanks is avance

Comment: Do you see somewhere that the control is working like you are expecting ? How we can help you if it is created like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all your own CSS from the page where you declare this RadWindow. Most likely, some of it is interfering with the RadWindow elements. Details on troubleshooting this are available here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-troubleshooting-distorted-appearance.html.

Also, this does not look to me like one of the built-in skins, so its is a custom one. Try using one of the built-in. If it is ok then something in your own skin breaks things so you need to fix it.

Third idea - switch to Lightweight RenderMode as it uses semantic elements and no tables so the CSS interference may be gone.